# How to bind method by passing the method name via a variable to @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm still quite new to vuejs and was watching one of many videos online to teach myself, when a question came to my mind.

With vuetify I build a navigation drawer that is looping (v-for) through a list of menu items and printing the details of the items with v-if.

Now for the question I have:
In vuejs, is there a way to bind a method from vues 'methods' like `singOut()` to an `@click` by passing the method with a variable.

`@click="item.method"` and `@click="{item.method}"` didn't work for me.

Clearification: There could be more methods than `singOut()` I would want to bind to `@click`. Because of that I'm looking for a more dynamic way to bind the method.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: {
   items: [
      { icon: "lightbulb_outline", text: "Notes", path: '/tools/notes' },
      { icon: "access_alarm", text: "Worktime", path: '/tools/worktime' },
      { divider: true },
      { heading: "Labels" },
      { icon: "add", text: "Create new label" },
      { divider: true },
      { heading: "Account" },
      { icon: "lock_open", text: "Login", path: '/signin' },
      { icon: "mdi-account-plus", text: "Sign Up", path: '/signup' },
      { icon: "mdi-logout", text: "Sign Out", method: 'singOut()' },
      { divider: true },
      { icon: "settings", text: "Settings", path: '/' },
      { icon: "chat_bubble", text: "Trash", path: '/' },
      { icon: "help", text: "Help", method: 'sendAlert("Really want to delete?")' },
      { icon: "phonelink", text: "App downloads", method: 'sendAlert("Leaving the app")' },
      { icon: "keyboard", text: "Keyboard shortcuts", path: '/' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   navigateTo(path) {
      if (path) {
        this.$router.push(path);
      } else {
        this.$router.push('/');
      }
    },
    singOut(){
      this.$store.dispatch('singOut');
    },
    sendAlert(msg) {
     alert(msg);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,i) in items">
      <span v-if="item.heading" :key="i"><b>{{item.heading}}</b></span>
      <span v-else-if="item.divider" :key="i">--------</span>
      <span v-else-if="item.method" @click="item.method" :key="i" style="cursor:pointer;">{{item.text}} (+ @click->Method)</span>
      <span v-else> {{item.text}} -> {{item.path}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmajap)

Split method in method-name and argument properties. 
You can create for example `call` method which calls passed function with passed arguments `@click="call(item.method, item.args)"`.

```
<v-btn v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="call(item.method, item.args)">
  {{item.text}}
</v-btn>

items: [
  ...
  { id: 5, text: "5", method: "methodTwo", args: ["Another message", 123] },

methods: {
  call(method, args = []) {
    this[method](...args)
  },
```

Make custom assertions as needed.
Any flaw in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have `singOut()` in your `methods: {}`, in your html for `@click`, just use `@click="singOut(item.method)"`

Your `singOut()` must be able to accept the params.

```
singOut(method) {
  // method here
  console.log(method)
}
```

---

I think this is not what you want to achieve because your method in the object consists of functions.

Using your current data:

```
items: [
  { icon: 'help', text: 'Help', method: 'Some method here', alert: 'Really want to delete?' }
]
```

What I suggest you could do is

- Have another property `alert` and set the string to it.
- Bind the `@click` event to a method with the item as the params; use that method to trigger an `alert()` with the `alert` property value in it.

Example:

```
singOut(item) {
  // handle the alert if it exists
  if (item.alert) {
    this.sendAlert(item.alert)
  } 

  // handle the method value
  console.log(item.method)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
I know that I could just bind the method directly to the `@click` like you said. But there are more methods than `signOut()` (eg. `sendAlert`) and there could be even more I wanted to pass.

In this case I can't just use `@click="singOut(item.method)"` because I then wouldn't be able to also bind the other methods.

Does this make it clearer?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check if the updated answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I'm sorry I probably confuse you with the given methods. They have nothing to do with each other and are just examples for methods I want to bind to the `@click`. I'm looking for a generic way to bind methods to `@click`without explicitly binding a given method to it.